# Website login not recognizing getelementbyID method

Tags: javascript, forms, excel, vba, authentication

I'm relatively new to VBA.  I'm loving it.  I need to login to web pages and navigate a few pages.  I've been calling the login information easily with this* with no problems.  I came to a new website and it refuses to accept my input.  I've had to modify my code to this**.  Furthermore, when I say .elements("password") It enters the password in the URL line.  Even after I told it to use the correct ID.  What's REALLY strange is if you step through it, it won't work. It only works if you're running the macro.

What I do know is that there are some Javascript validation procedures so I can't just pass the value of the login, I have to type it in.  Hence the sendkeys.  What I don't get is why it will find the User ID box to place the login information, but it goes sideways when it reads the next line saying "put the password here."

I don't know VBA well enough to ask the right question. It should be something easy.

*

```
With ieDoc
    .getElementById("UsernameIDvar").Value = LoginVal
    .getElementById("PasswordIDvar").Value = PassVal
    .all("loginbuttonvar").Click
End With
```

**

```
ieDoc is Internetexplorer.Application.Documents
LoginVal and PassVal is a string pulled from an excel spreadsheet

With ieDoc.forms("lqLogin")
        .elements("user").Click
        SendKeys (LoginVal), True
        .elements("password").Click
        SendKeys (PassVal), True
        .submit
End With
```

Website Code:

```
<form id="lqLogin" name="lqLogin" method="post" action="" >
 <fieldset>
 <legend>Enter Login Information</legend>
  <table class="ctl_loginBox">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td><label for="User Id">User ID</label> <br>
     <input type="text" value="" maxlength="50" size="28"
      id="user" name="user" disabled="disabled"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><label for="Password">Password</label><br>
     <input type="password" value="" maxlength="50" size="28"
      id="password" name="password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><div class="ctl_btnPos"><a href="#bmg_msgContainer"
      class="ctl_btn ctl_btnLogin lqLoginBtn"><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      Login&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></a></div></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: `id`s in the HTML are `user` and `password`, you're trying to get something else... Also `label`s are both referring an non-existing element (`User Id` and `Password`). `id`s in HTML are case-sensitive.

Comment: I've tried the single * code and it will put in the information, but due to some javascript code, It won't recognize a passed value. It only recognizes the information if it's typed.  If you click the cell, the passed value disappears.

Comment: Update:
I am able to make the information post to the login form.  
I can't get the submit button to "click."  Documents.forms().submit does not work. Anyone have any ideas?  The button is in the code piece I posted.